# GRUB not going away when I try to uninstall Linux from a Windows 10/Xubuntu dual boot

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, xubuntu

I have a Windows 10/Xubuntu dual boot, and decided to get rid of Xubuntu, and just have Windows 10. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/) to get rid of Xubuntu. When I reboot after using the "bootrec.exe /fixmbr" command, however, the computer boots into the grub-rescue menu. Does this mean that grub wasn't actually uninstalled, and, if so, how do I fix it? If that's not the case, how to I get past the grub-rescue menu?

Comment: UEFI or legacy BIOS? It makes a difference. MBR is irrelevant if the PC is booted with UEFI.

Comment: @JohanMyréen UEFI

Answer (score 1):

In UEFI grub is installed in EFI system partition at /EFI/OS/grub.cfg. You have to delete grub from there.

Boot into live USB. Run:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

`/dev/sda1` is most likely the name of EFI partition. Use `fdisk -l` to list all partitions.

Go to `/mnt/EFI/OS(XUbuntu)` and delete grub from there or just delete this `/OS(XUbuntu)` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Grub may have been installed to a partition instead of the mbr. If this is the case all you need to do is fire up fdisk or your favorite partition editor and make sure that the windows partition is active ant that it is the only active partition. This should do the trick since you already ensured that you have a valid mbr.